# AutoMapper: ResolveUsing deprecated, replace with MapFrom

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In my solution in .NET Framework 4.8.1, I'm upgrading AutoMapper from 7.0.1 to 10.1.1.
This result in +800 errors because I'm using ResolveUsing and that method was deprecated.
Could I just find and replace all occurrences of ResolveUsing to MapFrom and call it a day?

Old Code Sample1:

```
.ForMember(rh => rh.Document, option => option.ResolveUsing<RHFileClass>())
```

New Code Sample1:

```
.ForMember(rh => rh.Document, option => option.MapFrom<RHFileClass>())
```

Old Code Sample2:

```
.ForMember(buzz => buzz.Id, option => option.ResolveUsing<AgendaPK>(data => AgendaPK.NewOrNull(data.number)));
```

New Code Sample2:

```
.ForMember(buzz => buzz.Id, option => option.MapFrom<AgendaPK>(data => AgendaPK.NewOrNull(data.number)));
```

I would say that 65% of my cases are like Sample1.

Does someone already faced a similar issue?

I tried to find and replace all the occurrences of ResolveUsing to MapFrom. No more inline error but my question is: Is it really gonna work?

Comment: Try it - and report back here ...

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#existing-resolveusing-usages